# Cannot find 'LocationsData' in scope

Tags: json, parsing, swiftui

[My project contains the JSON file 'LocationsData.json'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzOz5.png)

[An error is displayed 'Cannot find 'LocationsData' in scope'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxPPv.png)

(If needed - the following code is contained within my 'Data.swift' file, which is what the var 'locationsDataTypes' in the 'SearchRedirect.swift' is referencing)

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

let locationsDataTypes: [LocationsDataTypes] = load("LocationsData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
let data: Data

guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
}

do {
    data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
} catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
} catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
}
}

final class ImageStore {
typealias _ImageDictionary = [String: CGImage]
fileprivate var images: _ImageDictionary = [:]

fileprivate static var scale = 2

static var shared = ImageStore()

func image(name: String) -> Image {
    let index = _guaranteeImage(name: name)
    
    return Image(images.values[index], scale: CGFloat(ImageStore.scale), label: Text(name))
}

static func loadImage(name: String) -> CGImage {
    guard
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "jpg"),
        let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as NSURL, nil),
        let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't load image \(name).jpg from main bundle.")
    }
    return image
}

fileprivate func _guaranteeImage(name: String) -> _ImageDictionary.Index {
    if let index = images.index(forKey: name) { return index }
    
    images[name] = ImageStore.loadImage(name: name)
    return images.index(forKey: name)!
}
}
```

Comment: `LocationsData` isn't declared anywhere. Did you mean `locationsDataTypes`?

Answer (score 0):

As pawello2222 hinted, `locationsData` isn't declared anywhere.

I suspect that you have your `List` view builder function written incorrectly.

Instead of this...

```
List(LocationsData, id: \.id) { locationsDataTypes in
```

Try the following...

```
List(locationsDataTypes, id: \.id) { locationsData in
    ...
                Image(locationsData.imageName)
                    .resizable
    ...
}
```

Where `locationsDataTypes` is the collection, in your case the array of `LocationsDataTypes` and `locationsData` is the single instance of each iteration through that collection.

Also, when writing a question in stack overflow, best practice is to include the relevant code within a code block *in your question*, not accessed via a hyperlink. There are many reasons for this, here are a couple...

- it is easier for the SO community to copy and paste your code into their solution as a part of their response, saving us all a lot of time;
- links break, leaving your question without context for anyone who might have the same problem in the future.